# Simple Emoji Rebus

Tags: rebus, emoji

[image: Emoji rebus]

Each emoji represents a word or set of words. This should be fairly easy to get.

Comment: Note: Try pasting the emoji into something else (I used Discord) to see them better.

Comment:  = http://emojipedia.org/face-with-no-good-gesture/ ;  = http://emojipedia.org/open-hands-sign/ ; ⬆ = UP ; ⬇ = DOWN

Comment: This is what the question looks like on my Linux machine. http://i.stack.imgur.com/YPFxS.png Please consider taking a screenshot of your puzzle and uploading that image, so everyone can see it clearly.

Comment: can you use an image like [this](http://i.imgur.com/zbgqzxP.png) in bigger screenshot?

Comment: is it limp bizkit? http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/limpbizkit/rollinairraidvehicle.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is

> Never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down
>  (AKA a [Rickroll](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ))

**Edit:**
As it has been asked in the comments below my answer and it's probably not clear for everyone how I came to my answer, here are my thoughts:

> the first emoji with the arms crossed can be seen as a cross which can refer to stop, never, no, ...
>
>  the up and down arrows should be self explaining..
>
>  the second emoji with two hands showing was more a guess than knowing what it was supposed to be, but taking in the first emoji (and 4th) and the third (and 6th) I got **"Never [blank] up, never [blank] down"** and this highly suggests this beeing a rickroll (since the meme is rather common on the internet)

Comment: This possibility occurred to me but if the hands were used for two different words I will be incredibly disappointed.

Comment: I'm not getting the hands part. Can you explain how you got from the emoji to your answer?